# How to transform an OracleDB Table into a parquet file with Python

Tags: python, oracle, parquet, cx-oracle

I'm trying to convert an oracledb into parquet file with python. I'm new to big data and have never worked with parquet before. So far I have successfully connected to the database and creating a cursor with cx_Oracle. I have looked into pyspark and pandas, but not sure how to use them. Is there anyway to transform this data into parquet with another library? Thanks!

Comment: We've used [PyArrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html) to generate parquet files from JSON data, but it has a lot of methods to generate the schema and put the data into the table (including support of Pandas data frames).

Comment: You may also use sqoop for this

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory and Azure Synapse Analytics - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-parquet
Source can be oracle or any data source - sink /target can be parquet or any other formats

Comment: This isn't exactly "with python". I think that OP might want something they can run in their own script, rather than a cloud product they can target.